# How to add PostgreSQL comments on objects with rails/rake?

Tags: rake, rails-activerecord

I would like to add comments on objects such as database itself, tables, etc while using rake.  For example, when I issue `rake db:create` I'd like to automagically add a comment via PostgreSQL extended SQL statement (if the adapter doesn't support this directly), like

```
COMMENT ON DATABASE myapp_development IS 'Rails DB for project at c:/some/path/myapp/';
```

I'd like a similar behavior for ActiveRecord::Migration, if possible (by extracting RDoc?) for tables and columns.

It occurs to me that this may be more like a feature request rather than something that could be done quickly.  Is this already possible to do, and how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just execute the raw SQL where you need it.  Try this:

```
sql = "COMMENT ON DATABASE myapp_development IS 'Rails DB for project at c:/some/path/myapp/';"
records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Note that you can use string interpolation (e.g. `"#{value}"`) to include variable values if you need.  You have all the expressive power of Ruby and the ability to run any native SQL that you need.

The [MigrationComments](https://github.com/pinnymz/migration_comments) gem gives inline support for comments on migration objects.  To install it, simply add this to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'migration_comments'
```

Once installed, you can include both inline comments:

```
def self.up
  create_table :users, comment: "User records are stored in this table." do |t|
    t.string :canonical_email, comment: "This column contains the email address that has been URL decoded and lowercased, to ensure system-wide uniqueness"
  end
end
```

and standalone comment changes:

```
def self.up
  change_table :users do |t|
    t.comment "User records are stored in this table."
    t.change_comment :canonical_email, "This column contains the email address that has been URL decoded and lowercased, to ensure system-wide uniqueness"
  end
end
```

You can find the [PgComment](https://github.com/albertosaurus/pg_comment) gem that will give you commenting with an ActiveRecord-like syntax.  Simply add this to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'pg_comment'
```

And you'll be able to do cool things like this:

```
set_table_comment :users, "User records are stored in this table."
set_column_comment(:users, :canonical_email, "This column contains the email address that has been URL decoded and lowercased, to ensure system-wide uniqueness")
```

Unfortunately, there's no `set_database_comment` with either gem, so database comments (and other unsupported Postgres objects) would require use of the raw SQL solution shown at the top of the answer.

Comment: Where do I put all this to be triggered from `rake db:create`?

Comment: Great question.  You can actually conveniently do it from within the migrations.  So, your first migration might have this to comment the database, and then begin creating tables.

Comment: Uhm! That can work. But it seems too verbose to add code like that with every migration manually. I'd rather prefer wrap it in gem and have it hooked for migrations if something like that is even possible.

Comment: There is a gem that does some of it, and I included those details in my answer.  You'd need to use both techniques to comment everything.

Comment: Actually, there were 2 gems, and I added information for both, including basic usage for the object types that they support.

Comment: I guess I overlooked what is out there. *MigrationComments* seems promising. I want whatever approach to pass silently if non-PG is used. And this gem supports common alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out it is easier than I thought. One can create `./lib/tasks/annotate_db.rake`, e.g., from [Rails template file](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html), with the following content

```ruby
namespace :db do
  def update_db_comment
    Rails.configuration.database_configuration.each do |key, hash|
      db = hash['database']
      if not db.nil?
        sql = "COMMENT ON DATABASE #{db} IS 'Rails #{Rails::VERSION::STRING} #{key} DB for project at #{Rails.root} on #{Socket.gethostbyname(Socket.gethostname).first}';"
        # puts sql
        records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
      end
    end
  end

  task :create do
    update_db_comment
  end
end

# Rake::Task['db:create'].enhance(['db:set_db_comment'])
```